# 24 hours in minutes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, time

How to convert `24.hours` into minutes it gives me second.

```
1.9.3p392 :076 > 24.hours
=> 86400 seconds
```

One NON-RUBY way is

```
1.9.3p392 :079 > 24*60
 => 1440
```

Is there any ruby or rails way of doing this? `i.e. 24.hours_in_minutes`

Comment: What do you want to use "24 hours in minutes" for? If you want to add it to a `Time`, `24.hours` is all you need (it doesn't matter that it prints as "86400 seconds" at the REPL).

Comment: There's always division.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most appropriate way to do this is probably:

```
24.hours / 1.minute
```

This way you keep the readability and clear intention of the 'ruby mindset'.

Of course, this will have a constant value so you should probably store it in an appropriately named constant (e.g. `MINUTES_IN_A_DAY`) rather than calculating it every time.

Comment: Needs at least `require 'active_support/all'` or else `NoMethodError (undefined method 'hours' for 24:Integer)`   (PORO / Outside of Rails)

Comment: @Marcos It should be enough to just require `active_support/time` - you don't need all of it.

Answer (score 5):

### in_minutes (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces new [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) conversion methods like [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as simple as:

```
24.hours.in_minutes
# => 1440.0
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38699).

Comment: Yet another reason to upgrade to Rails 6. Some slick stuff right here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a short way. This will return in seconds

`24.hours.to_i` or `1.day.to_i`

`wil return 86400`

Comment: Interesting. Not very clear though. If you do end up using this, definitely add a comment for your fellow programmers so they know what's going on.

Comment: Also, this returns **minutes**, not **seconds**, as OP was asking for.